# In flutter, the softkeyboard does not appear. instead, a white screen appears on the screen

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I'm getting an error in the soft keyboard in flutter when I click on a textfield and it opens a white screen as the keyboard.

I attempted to locate the specific issue but was unable to do so.

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: GetBuilder<LoginController>(builder: (ctrl) {
        return BaseScreen(
          isLoding: controller.isLoding,
          onOutSideClick: () {
            controller.stopLoading();
          },
          child: AppView(
            appChild: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  AppStartUpTextField(
                    controller: ctrl.emailTextFieldController,
                    hint: emailText,
                    textInputType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    errorText: ctrl.emailErrorText.isNotEmpty
                        ? ctrl.emailErrorText
                        : null,
                  ),
                  30.spaceH(),
                  AppStartUpTextField(
                    controller: ctrl.passwordTextFieldController,
                    hideText: ctrl.hidePasswordText,
                    maxLine: 1,
                    showSuffix: true,
                    errorText: ctrl.passWordText.isNotEmpty
                        ? ctrl.passWordText
                        : null,
                    onSuffixTap: () {
                      ctrl.hidePasswordText = !ctrl.hidePasswordText;
                      ctrl.update();
                    },
                    hint: passwordText,
                  ),
                  15.spaceH(),
                  ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Container())
                
                ],
              ).paddingSymmetric(horizontal: 30),
            ),

          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```

In scaffold, I set resizeToAvoidBottomInset to true.

Comment: Add your code sample

Comment: Can I see your code please?

Comment: Hey @AlexSunderSingh
I have edited my question with my code

Comment: Hey @SagarRAnghan  I have edited my question with my code

Comment: Where do you have background design?, I mean in which widget

Comment: what you mean? @AlexSunderSingh

Comment: Code missing for `BaseScreen` and `AppView`

Comment: `class BaseScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget child;
  bool isLoding;
  GestureTapCallback? onOutSideClick;

  BaseScreen(
      {super.key,
      required this.child,
      required this.isLoding,
      this.onOutSideClick});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        child,
        isLoding
            ? LoadingStack(onOutSideClick)
            : Container()
      ],
    );
  }
}`
 
this is my BaseScreen widget

Answer (score 1):

Wrap with your widget like this .

```
return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child:YourWidgets(),
             );
    );
```